# How do I inherit images in sub-theme from base theme?

Tags: theming

We built a drupal theme **"Theme A"** from scratch for our project. Later , for the new releases , we wanted to modify the newly developed pages which were slightly enhanced versions of previous pages. In order to retain most of the css and js , we created a sub theme **"Theme B"** from **"Theme A"** . Now most of the images which we had used earlier are in **Theme A's image** folder. How do we reuse Theme A's images in Theme B without copying them ? The current default theme is set to **"Theme B"**.

We used *base_path().path_to_theme()* to refer images. I guess we must now change it to *drupal_get_path('theme','themeA')*.

Comment: From css and js files, you just call relative paths like so:
background-image: url(../../theme_a/images/my-image.jpg);

From php files, you can call the drupal_get_path() function like so:
$themeAPath = drupal_get_path('theme', 'theme_a');